# MPI_Datatype for C++ container

Tags: c++, serialization, mpi

How can I define `MPI_Datatype`s and `MPI_Op`s so that MPI communication routines can be used with C++ containers?

In my specific case, I'd like to union a (distributed) array of `std::set<int>`s using `MPI_Allreduce`.

According to the related questions

- [Mpi_allgather and mpi_pack in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9879355/985943)
- [MPI_reduce() with custom Datatype containing dynamically allocated arays : segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13434879/985943)
- [Creating an MPI_Datatype for a structure containing pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10419990/985943)

it seems that this requires (un-)serializing the container data. In my case, the `size()` of each `std::set` varies widely, and I am interested in a solution that does not require padding (if possible).

Comment: Are you saying that serializing/deserializing the data requires padding? I don't see why...

Comment: From what I understand, the width of `MPI_Datatype` is fixed; in the specific case I mentioned above, this width would be `MySets[i].size()*sizeof(int)` which varies for each `i`. So, I imagine I would have to pad the serialization of each `MySet` element to some common length in order to have the same `MPI_Datatype` for the `MPI_Allreduce`.

Comment: Ah. Yes, that would be a problem. You could at least break each `set` into many blocks of the same size, so that only the last block of each `set` needs padding.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. How would you define `MPI_Op` (and `MPI_Datatype`) to handle the possibility that the union of two blocks (subsets) may be larger than the blocksize? Unless you padded in advance...

Comment: Also, I don't think `boost::mpi` supports this, since `std::set` isn't POD: "[...]any POD ("Plain Old Data") type containing types that themselves can be represented by MPI data types can itself be represented as an MPI data type." ([`boost::mpi::is_mpi_datatype`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/mpi/is_mpi_datatype.html))

Comment: In messages, I'd represent the `set`s as arrays of `int`s, so that they would be POD. As for the overflow problem...yeah, padding in advance might be the only way to do it. The return type of `MPI_Op` must be the same type as `MPI_Datatype`, right?

Comment: Yes, I think this follows from associativity of `MPI_Op`. I would accept an implementation of your suggestion as an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately that will probably have to wait for a couple days...